# How can I pass arguments to a docker container with a python entry-point script using command?

Tags: python, docker

So I've got a docker image with a python script as the entry-point and I would like to pass arguments to the python script when the container is run. I've tried to get the arguments using sys.argv and sys.stdin, but neither has worked. I'm trying to run the container using:

```
docker run image argument
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It depends how the entrypoint was set up. If it was set up in "exec form" then you simply pass the arguments after the `docker run` command, like this:

```
docker run image -a -b -c
```

If it was set up in "shell form" then you have to override the entrypoint, unfortunately.

```
$ docker run --entrypoint echo image hi
hi
```

You can check the form using `docker inspect`. If the entrypoint appears to begin with `/bin/sh -c`, then it is shell form.

References:

- http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime
- http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: It seems (maybe due to newer docker version) that this does not depend on whether it is specified in shell form or in exec form. According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint `Command line arguments to docker run <image> will be appended after all elements in an exec form ENTRYPOINT, and will override all elements specified using CMD.`, so use ENTRYPOINT if you want to add something later and CMD if you want to override it later.

Comment: For quick reference: **shell form** is `ENTRYPOINT foo --bar` and **exec form** is `ENTRYPOINT ["foo", "--bar"]`