# How to execute jar file in docker

Tags: docker, jar

A jar need to deploy in docker.I know how to write Dockerfile for a running jar.
this jar is a commandline option application.it has serveral arguments.and will be needed to run serveral times with different arguments.
for example. It has `arg1,arg2`.

User can run with `arg1=A,arg2=B` then run with `arg1=A2`. No `arg2`.

Docker cannot run this, i have specified these arguments when they run and the container stop once the jar main task finished. I need to start another container to run jar.

Don't think this is friendly. My question is **in this case, is it not suitable to deploy with docker?**

Comment: How did you try to run this in your container?

Comment: define docker run arguments,and pass it to run container

Comment: I think you can pass the arguments when running the container. Like this: `docker run image -a -b -c` . See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31523657/4151472

Comment: @RichArt: `docker run` starts a new container. It does appear that the OP wants to run them one after the other in the same container

Comment: @n2o yeah. I want them in the same container.it is unfriendly for user to run in different container.

Comment: Than you have to follow the answer given by @Mgccon: start a fresh container and send the commands into it with `docker exec ...`
Or you start an interactive session inside the container with `docker exec -it <your-image> bash` and rund the commands interactively in this shell

Comment: Were you successful with any of the described setups?

Comment: have tried the method you have described.write a loop in bash script.and run it when container begin to start.it can solve my problem.but "docker stop" command cannot stop it.

Comment: sorry for last update.have made a mistake."docker stop" command can stop it.just starting container,cannot finish the commandline,cannot do nothing in this shell.as it continue to run.need to multiple shell and run "docker stop" command.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the container to run a script that will never end just to keep the container running.
As an example you can include the following in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo 'sleep infinity' >> /bootstrap.sh && chmod +x /bootstrap.sh
```

You can start the container in the following way:

```
docker run -d --name <container-name> <image> ./bootstrap.sh
```

To run the jar you can use:

```
docker exec <container-name> java [arguments]
```

Having in mind it is a java program and it is OS agnostic you don't have a huge benefit in running inside a container but is possible.

Comment: actually i dont expect any benefit with running in a container.just needed to deploy in docker.can you clarify how to keep the container running in a script.sorry I don't get the point.I thought container lifecycle binded to the jar main task.

Comment: The container is driven by the process with pid 1. If the process is running so is the container. Once the process ends the container will stop.
That is what is happening when you run java command.
If instead you run a script that contains an infinite loop as pid 1 the container will never stop. Check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818938/how-to-keep-an-infinite-loop-running-in-order-to-not-close-a-container-in-docker)
This will allow to execute commands in the running container with "docker exec".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple "hack" for this purpose... But I do not think this is the best solution.

Start a container with a process that is not supposed to be ended soon, e.g. `bash`. Also, lets say you want to use the latest ubuntu image. Then you can start the container with:

```
$ docker run -d -it ubuntu bash
```

This starts a ubuntu container and keeps it running <strike>as a daemon</strike> edit: detached (`-d`) in the background.

Lets lookup the container's name:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE    COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS         NAMES
59104211e795   ubuntu   "bash"    2 seconds ago   Up 1 seconds   jolly_hawking
```

It is *jolly_hawking*. Your commands (here: `ls /`) can then be sent to the container with this command:

```
$ docker exec jolly_hawking ls /
```

But that is definitely not the best solution. Maybe just keep this as an example how this might work for you and how Docker containers are working.

Comment: This is similar to what i propose but with the downside the container will stop when the  bash times out.
The -d option in the run command actually means that the container will be "detached" meaning it will not stop once you close the shell.

Comment: Yes it is the same, but backed with an example.